# Excel Formula to Search One Cell and Replace Text in Another Cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've been searching all over and found a lot of posts that are almost what I need, but nothing exactly right. Hoping someone here can help.

I have two columns of data, column H contains broker names (Broker1, Broker2, etc). Column I contains the name of the company they rep (ABC, BBC, etc). These affiliations change often so I am looking for a way to setup a formula or macro for quick changes. Essentially what I want to do is say "If the cell I2 contains company ABC, change H2 to Broker2."

All the substitute and replace functions seem to be centered around replace all Broker1 with Broker2, but I need to be able to make this change only when a certain company is involved. Broker2 may rep 20 companies, so I need to be able to limit the find and replace to certain data elements.

Hope this all makes sense, thanks in advance for the help!

Adding details:
Ok, so a real life example. A company named Elite represents Kellogg's. H2 = "Elite" and I2 = 'Kellogg's". However, Kellogg's may change over to another company named Core. So I need to go search I2:I200 and wherever we find "Kellogg's" replace H with "Core". So if I78 = "Kellogg's" I need to change H78 to "Core". Trouble is, Elite may rep 20 other companies who don't move, so I can't completely replace all of Elite with Core on my list, only in very certain circumstances

Comment: add an example to make it clearer

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. As Ted suggest, an example would help a great deal. Also what have you tried so far? The more information you can give us, the better help we can be to you :-)

Comment: Edit your question. There is an `edit` link above the comments and below the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Rep Change

### Excel

You could create a unique list of company names and add the representatives. Then you could use an `INDEX/MATCH` formula in the representative column (`H`), something like this:

[image]

Then you could change `Elite` in one place only (`M7`) and it would automatically change in all the cells of the `H` column, e.g. `H4`.

### VBA

If you need it for one time operations, the following code might be helpful. Adjust the constants to fit your needs.

```vb
Sub RepChange()

    Const Company As String = "Kellog's"
    Const Representer As String = "Elite"
    Const NewRepresenter As String = "Core"

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const cColRep As Variant = "H"
    Const cColComp As Variant = "I"
    Const cFR As Long = 2

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        LR = .Columns(cColComp).Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = cFR To LR
            If StrComp(.Cells(i, cColComp), Company, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
                    StrComp(.Cells(i, cColRep), Representer, vbTextCompare) _
                    = 0 Then .Cells(i, cColRep) = NewRepresenter
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox "Operation finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

`StrComp` with `vbTextCompare` is used to avoid case-sensitivity i.e. AA=Aa=aa.

Or you could use this:

```
Sub RepChange2(Company As String, Representer As String, _
        NewRepresenter As String)

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const cColRep As Variant = "H"
    Const cColComp As Variant = "I"
    Const cFR As Long = 2

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        LR = .Columns(cColComp).Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = cFR To LR
            If StrComp(.Cells(i, cColComp), Company, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
                    StrComp(.Cells(i, cColRep), Representer, vbTextCompare) _
                    = 0 Then .Cells(i, cColRep) = NewRepresenter
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

where you could write even several statements in a sub like this one:

```
Sub Kellogs()
    RepChange2 "Kellog's", "Elite", "Core"
End Sub
```